# Output the first paragraph in a Wordpress post

Tags: php, wordpress

I want to put just the first paragraph of my posts on my index.php

in my functions.php I have

```
<?php

{
global $post;

$output = get_the_content();

$wanted_number_of_paragraph = 1;

$tmp = explode ('</p>', $output);
for ($i = 0; $i < $wanted_number_of_paragraph; ++$i) {
if (isset($tmp[$i]) && $tmp[$i] != '') {
   $tmp_to_add[$i] = $tmp[$i];
}
}
$output = implode('</p>', $tmp_to_add) . '</p>';

echo $output;

}
?>
```

then in my index.php

```
<?php wpden_excerpt(); ?>
```

However it posts the entire post (including pictures) and not just the first paragraph.

Comment: possible duplicate of https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/127159/grab-the-first-paragraph-of-each-post

Comment: Is '<?php wpden_excerpt(); ?>' appended to the contents of index.php or replacing the contents of index.php?

Comment: Agree with @charan kumar

Comment: That is where I looked first to see how others have done it. But couldn't get it to work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wold recommend you to use the Wordpress [get_extended()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_extended/) function for this purpose. In your post you split the content with the `"more"` tag, after inside your template you can have something like:

```
global $post;
// gets the content of your post as an array of 2 parts
$content_parts = get_extended( $post->post_content );
```

and after this you can echo the part before the `"more"` tag like:

```
<?=$content_parts['main'];?>
```

the part after the `"more"` tag you can echo like:

```
<?=$content_parts['extended'];?>
```

Also, if you chose this option I'll recommend you to check the [wpautop()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wpautop/) , since you may need to wrap these 2 parts with it, for example:

```
<?=wpautop($content_parts['extended']);?>
```